# Boundedness of random variable with a specific condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that some random variable $X$ satisfies $\mathbb{E} \exp(\lambda^2 X^2) ≤ \exp(\lambda^2 )$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $X$ is a bounded random variable, i.e. $\|X\|_{\infty} < \infty$.

Comment: what have you tried? Do you think it is true or false?

Comment: *Hint.* For any RV $Z$, we have $$\lim_{p\to\infty}\|Z\|_{L^p}=\|Z\|_{L^\infty}. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee I tried this in some ways but without any results.

Comment: @Exodd That's true, I have to prove it. I tried rewriting expected in some different ways, representing exponent as Taylor series, applying some inequalities.

Comment: Here is another hint: If both sides of the inequality are raised to the power of $\lambda^{-2}$, then $$\|e^{X^2}\|_{L^{\lambda^2}}=(\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda^2 X^2)])^{\lambda^{-2}} \leq e.$$ Now what happens if we take limit as $\lambda \to \infty$?

Comment: @SangchulLee that works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that
$$
\|e^{X^2}\|_{\lambda^2} = \left( \mathbb{E} \exp{\lambda^2 x^2} \right)^{1/\lambda^2} \leq \{\text{under the terms}\} \leq e
$$
We can only consider $\lambda \geq 1$, so it would be a $L$-norm. We can aim $\lambda$ to $\infty$ and then we have $\|e^{X^2}\|_{\infty} \leq e$, so $e^{X^2}$ is bounded. Then clear that $X$ is bounded as well.